# Custom bullet icon for <dt> tag using CSS not working

Tags: html, css

I want to add a description list with custom bullet icon for the `<dt>` tag using CSS. I tried several methods, but it's not working. For `<'li'>` it's working, but it won't work with `<dt>` tag.

I tried several methods including `list-style-image`, `list-style-type` and inline methods. I want to format it using CSS, because there are several `<dl>` lists.

```css
dt { list-style-image: url("icon.png"); }
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt><a href="#">Topic 1</a></dt>
  <dd>short description</dd>
</dl>
```

I want the custom image as the bullet point for `<dt>` tags, but it's not showing anything at all with the methods I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach to the main answer, what you were trying to do is possible, but it works only on elements with `display: list-item`, which `dt` does not have by default. So add that. Also, the bullet is to the left of the element, so you should add some padding to prevent it from being outside the viewport. That's all you need to change.

```css
dt {
  list-style-image: url('https://placehold.it/10x10');
  display:list-item;  /* to make it work */
  margin-left:2em;    /* to make it visible */
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt><a href="#">Topic 1</a></dt>
  <dd>short description</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This also works other than the main answer.

Answer (score 1):

`<dl>`s and their children cannot be styled as `<ul>/<ol>`s.

One approach is to add another HTML element into the `<dl>` and make it act as an icon.

```css
dt::before {
  content: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ce2677d0d36f4b4d4d17d1cc569d0375?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/** Apply some margin left to all dd, as we the image moves the dt a little bit to the right **/

dd {
  margin-left: 47px;
  /** we get the icon's width (see above) + its margin right + add some 10px more**/
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt><a href="#">Topic 1</a></dt>
  <dd>short description</dd>
</dl>
```

Another way is to wrap each `<dl>` in a `<ul>` and style its `<li>`, but I don't recommend that as it's not a very semantic HTML. :)

Here's an example, though:

```css
ul li {
  list-style-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ce2677d0d36f4b4d4d17d1cc569d0375?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt><a href="#">Topic 1</a></dt>
      <dd>short description</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
  <li>
    <dl>
      <dt><a href="#">Topic 2</a></dt>
      <dd>short description 2</dd>
    </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this and it's working, Thank you very much. But, is there another method to do this?

Comment: @DisuraRandunu, not that I can think of. You can wait for other answers, as well. I went through the CSS specification & HTML documentation about `dt`, `dl`, `dd`, but couldn't find any info as to why they cannot be styled as `ul`/`ol`s, even though you can always see them listed together in any tutorial/article.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova The trick is to use `display: list-item`; see my answer.

Comment: @MrLister, Obviously, I am still sleepy, haha, I tried this, but wrapped the value of `display` in single quotes. 

Answer (score 0):

list-style-image property for list-item displays. So if you use this property your parent element display must be list-item.